# Reliability of a system

Tags: statistics

I would like to say something about the reliability of the system I designed; to give an impression that it works well.

I did 40 tests, and in every case the system gave the right answer. 
How do I say something 'statisticly' about this? I know I can't say it works right every time, but what can I say?

Comment: What does the system do? Is it some sort of logistic regression system?

Comment: Did you separate training and testing set? Did you try cross-validation? Is the data biased?

Comment: It's a system that automaticly measure things, and I want to verify that it measure things right. I can verify by measuring the same object by hand.

Comment: So you are always testing on the same object?

Comment: The same kind of objects, but not exactly the same (example: length of different screws, surface of different plates, etc.).

Comment: Do you have an idea of theoretical errors the system makes? Because otherwise you can only say "it's robust in the tested cases"...